# Example of function which behaves linearly on $[0,1]$ and admits an asymptote as $x\to \infty$

Tags: functions, asymptotics, constraints

**Problem :**

Let $f(x)$ be a positive  differentiable function on $x>0$ such that :

Let $x\in[0,\varepsilon]$,$0<\varepsilon<1$ such that :

$$f(x)\simeq ax+b$$

And :

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)-cx-d=0$$

I can exhibit a such function see :

$$f\left(x\right)=\frac{x}{\left(x^{x}\ln\left(x^{x}+1\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{x^{x}}}}$$

But it's a very exotic function .

Question :

Can you provide some simple example for $f(x)$ ?

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks for pointing I correct .

Answer (score 4):

Basically we want $f(x)$ to behave like $ax+b$ for small $x$ and $cx+d$ for large $x$, therefore we can define a 'switch' function $s(x)$ such that $s(x)\approx1$ for small $x$ and $s(x)\approx0$ for large $x$, then let
$$f(x)=s(x)(ax+b)+(1-s(x))(cx+d).$$
A simple example would be $s(x)=\frac1{1+x^2}$, which gives
$$f(x)=\frac{ax+b}{1+x^2}+\left(1-\frac1{1+x^2}\right)(cx+d)=\frac{cx^3+dx^2+ax+b}{1+x^2}.$$
Here is a [Desmos plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ksrp8zudin) to visualise this function.

Comment: Interesting thanks you !

Comment: @Wolframandgromit You are welcome :)